# javascript file in subdirectory not loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I build a simple ASP MVC4 application which uses ExtJS.

My main view has link to my main employee.js file:

```
<script src="app/employee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm publishing my application to server in my local network.
On my development machine when I access url `http:\\local-iis\holidays` application is loaded correctly and displayed.
But on 3 others computers in the same network I get error, because browser can't find that js file.

My project structure looks like so:

```
--holidays (project name)
  +--app
     +--myapp.js
  +--Controllers
  +--Models
  +--(rest of ASP folders)
```

On my development machine when I access `http:\\local-iis\holidays` on chrome and I inspect source I see line:

```
<script src="app/employee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

after I rollover that entry

[image]

I see correct path:

```
http:\\local-iis\holidays\app\employee.js  (I translated urlopy to holidays)
```

on other computers for the same page source directory name is removed (`holidays`)

I tried clearing cache, installing other browsers, switching to other computers but everything failed-on some computers this is working and on some it isn't.

I'm not asking for specific solution, but something to get started with.

It's my first project in MVC 4 and I don't know how should I configure my application to get those urls working.

I don't know why my application is removing that directory name (it is referring to root of my local-iis server)

I asked on ExtJS forum and they said this is probably IIS or ASP setting issue.

Comment: The backslash is throwing me off.  Do you really have this or did you mean `/`

Comment: @MikeChristensen which backslash do You mean?

Comment: All of them.  For example, `http:\\local-iis\holidays\app\employee.js`

Comment: @MikeChristensen I added screenshot to show what I mean with those backslashes.

Comment: I don't see any backslashes in your screenshot.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Sorry for that, I already replaced it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<script src="app/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just use helpers:

```
<script src="~/app/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `~/app/myapp.js` will properly go through the `Url.Content` helper which in turn will generate the correct url no matter where your application is hosted. For example if your application is hosted locally in IIS Express it might look like this:

```
<script src="/app/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and when deployed in a virtual directory in IIS it might look like this:

```
<script src="/holidays/app/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The helper will take care of it.

In Razor v1.0 (ASP.NET MVC 3) you would have to explicitly use the helper:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/app/myapp.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this, I was able to get my main file loaded, but rest of js files can't be configured like this, because they are loaded dynamically using ExtJS. When I move my application to normal folder it is loading correctly, but I need it to load from ASP.NET folder

Comment: In this case you could pass the base root url of your application to your javascript files. It should be calculated on the server. For example you could have a global javascript variable: `<script type="text/javascript">var basePath = '@Url.Content("~/")';</script>;` which you would then use in your scripts. Don't look for miracles, there aren't any. You should never hardcode urls, and always use url helpers in an ASP.NET MVC application if you want it to work properly. Everytime you hardcode an url it will break.

Comment: SO there isn't any config option for ASP.NET application to disable subdirectory removing? I might be wrong, but this should be an option, not always application must be in root.

Comment: This is just a suggestion but maybe this can be done using `RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute`?